# Why new controllers are not working for React Template on .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm starting code with ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and React starter template, but after hours of research, I can't figure out what's wrong.

The template has this controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public Object Test()
    {
        return new int [] {};
    }
}
```

I created the method `Test` and navigating to `/weatherforecast/test`, I get an empty array correctly, but my problem comes when I create new controllers and try to access to the new endpoints. The server redirects me to `index.html` page

This is a controller sample

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Object Get()
    {
        return new int [] {};
     }
 }
```

I tested with `[Route("[controller]")]`, `[Route("weather")]` and typing in browser url `/weather` or `/api/weather` and I always see the main page with the top navbar and I expect that returns a json result with an empty array. Please any help will be appreciated.

This is the content of `Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production 
    scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Hi @Dariel Ramos, does the `WeatherForecastController` and  `WeatherController` both exist in react project? If so, it seems to be impossible to appear what you said. If it is 404, both of the two controllers are all 404. Please check your WeatherForecastController again. Besides, it contains two port number if you use react project in asp.net 6. When you run the application, it will display a panel and tells you the proxy port number and local port number. If you want to call api, you need use the proxy port number to send request.

Comment: For detailed explanation, if the request is 404, it will fall back to index.html like what you said with only navbar.

Comment: @Rena I open the browser devtools and inspect all the requests sent from react and just change the last part of the url according to my new endpoints and nothing happens. Ex: Original requests https://localhost:4221/weatherforecast changed to https://localhost:4221/weather It makes me think that only can have a controller in my project something  weird really

Comment: I want to consume my endpoints outside the app because after developing the backend and some manage system for the front I'll create a mobile app and therefore these questions are very important to me

Comment: @Rena You're right I was trying to get the JSON result of my API from the incorrect port. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

In my case it is solved by the following steps:

1. Opening ClientApp\src\setupProxy.js
2. Adding the required path in to the `context` const:

```js
const context =  [
  "/weatherforecast",
  "/api" // <-- this is an added item
];
```

My intuitive understanding is that default template is running some react development http server that redirects requests to ASP.NET core server by patterns configured in this file.

If a requested path does not match pattern, it serves it itself, so our requests do not reach ASP.NET core server.

Comment: this solved my problem, due to this context C# controller was not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

Net 6 react template separates the front-end (react) from the backend (C# web apis) by deploying locally to different ports.
You can check your launchSettings.json to see the port the application is being deployed:
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7027;http://localhost:5027",

If you are not able to find it there, then check the ClientApp/src/setupProxy.js to see what port is being used:

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:6973';